# How can I force all web browsers to reload a page on click of back button of the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a admin page where user updates the number, but when i hit the back button it still shows the old value in the textbox feild, here is my code.

```html
<?php
//following code to update the ticket avaiable number
if(isset($save))
{
//To insert number into database
 Data::getupdate($ticketsavailable); 
 print('<script>window.location.href="https://ct.org/gun-drawing-nocache1/"</script>');
}
//following code for to show the available tickets on the text box
$ticketleft = "";
//this will fetch number from database
$ticketleft = Data::getticketsavailable();

}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>update page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<label class="update_heading"> Update Gun Drawing Tickets </label> <br>
  <label for="update" class="update"> Update Number: </label><input type="textbox" id="ticketsavailable" name="ticketsavailable" value="<?php
                         echo  $ticketleft[0]->ticket_available ;?>" >
       <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">


 <script type="text/javascript">    
// If persisted then it is in the page cache, force a reload of the page.
        window.onpageshow =function(event){
            if(event.persisted){        
                document.body.style.display ="none";        
                location.reload();
            }
        };
</script>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

//I have used javascript: but it doesnot work for Chrome
also I have tried there headers on page still does not work.
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"); //Date in the past
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); //HTTP/1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: When you go back in history in your browser, browser does NOT make a new request for your page. Instead it shows a saved instance of the last page you visited.(in Chrome). So this being said, you cannot do this the easy way. Oor there is another possibility that i just misunderstood your back button for the back button of the browser.

Comment: ohh sorry It's "back button of the browser"

Comment: You need something to hold your state of the webpage. In order for you to know if the state changed. Either this, or you need a notification infrastructure like firebase, to notify you from time-to-time when the page is being redirected. (not practical at all, and also not good for this case). 
The last choice you have, is programming an extension to make you do this, because you are wanting functionality in the browser level, and not just the page level anymore. Good Luck